# How to get all properties set on a groovy closure from java

Tags: groovy

I am looking at this and our code calls closure.setProperty a bit.  I do not see a getProperties method though to read the properties

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/2.4.4/groovy/lang/Closure.java#Closure

A snippit of the generated groovy is

```
_attrs82 = [defaultArgument:'entity.firstName', label:'First Name']; //htmlLine 23:23  groovyLine=64

_body82 = { //htmlLine 23:23  groovyLine=67
  __out.print("<input type=\"text\" name=\""); //htmlLine 23:23  groovyLine=69
   __out.print(field.name); //htmlLine 23:23  groovyLine=72
  __out.print("\" value=\""); //htmlLine 23:23  groovyLine=75
   __out.print(field.flashOrValue); //htmlLine 23:23  groovyLine=78
  __out.print("\" class=\"input-xlarge\">"); //htmlLine 23:23  groovyLine=81
}; //htmlLine 23:23  groovyLine=82

runTag('field', _attrs82, _body82, 'at WEBPIECESxPACKAGE.base.crud.userAddEdit.html(userAddEdit.html:23)'); //htmlLine 23:23  groovyLine=84
```

thanks,
Dean

Comment: Would you mind showing the sample code that you working on? By the way, there is `getProperty` method.

Comment: If you mean what i think you mean, you can't... You could set a map as the delegate, and use this to expose properties i guess

Comment: @tim_yates very interesting.  I do have a GroovyTemplateSuperclass extends Script as well.  perhaps if I have a setProperty there.  gives me something to look into